# Need recommendations on a Freezer to Kegarator Conversion

Tags: beer, equipment

Built a bar with a concrete counter top. Already have the 3.5 inch hole for the beer Tap. I'm planning on converting a freezer into a Kegarator. Any suggestions on models ?

Also, can we use a chest freezer on its side so it opens on the side instead of the top ? Is that possible ? something like this : https://www.danby.com/products/freezers/dcf035b1wm/

pls share any recommendations or thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter the model, just pick one that fits your capacity and space needs.  As for putting it on its side, you can't do that.  The compressor and cooling fluids are arranged to work with gravity to an extent and they need to be upright.  In a chest freezer that means it needs to sit on its feet.  You can get upright freezers though if that's really how you want to do it.  But if you're doing that why not just go with a fridge unit?  You're better off with a fridge anyway for many reasons; especially if you want it to open from the front.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a freezer as it:

1. has the potential to freeze your beer
2. You generally get more internat space
3. fridge does not need additional temp controller, if you do add a temp controller to a freezer, you need to add a wait in so it does not spin up and down the compressor too frequently.

As Brewchez said - DO NOT put a freezer or fride in any other orientation that the one it is designed to be used in.